# how to load module model class in CI main controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using HMVC strucutre in Code Igniter, where I need to load module model class insider base CI controller or helper how can I do this.

i.e: load faq model in side view_helper

[folder strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EffpK.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load a model in your helper the same way as you can load it in your controller:

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');
```

Once loaded, you will access your model functions using an object with the same name as your class:

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');

$this->Model_name->function();
```